# Getting data from AJAX call empty request array

Tags: ajax, post, request

My data from an AJAX request seems to be arriving (in JS) but I'm getting an undefined index error in the request (in PHP).

JS:

```
$.ajax(
        { 
            url: "cidades.ajax.php",
            data: {estado : $(this).val()},
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            cache: false,   
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
```

PHP:

```
$cod_estados =  $_REQUEST['estado'];
```

Inspector Request Pay load is being set to 
`estado=3` in the inspector.

I'm getting the following response.

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: estado in <b>F:\projetos\bt\agentes\cidades.ajax.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
[]
```

I'd appreciate any help, thanks....

Comment: Fixed it by using dataType: "json", now the data is arriving on the php page.  The problem now is that when I try to return the data as JSON it won't give any response.

Comment: echo( json_encode( $res ) );

If I send only a string with echo it goes perfectly...